# Wrong time format fetched

Tags: node.js

I am using Node for fetching data from MySQL. In database, i got record like : 2013-08-13 15:44:53 . But when Node fetches  from Database , it assigns value like 2013-08-19T07:54:33.000Z.

I just need to get time  format as in MySQL table. Btw ( My column format is DateTime in MySQL)

In Node :

```
connection.query(post, function(error, results, fields) {

    userSocket.emit('history :', {
        'dataMode': 'history',
        msg: results,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving it from the database you most likely get a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object which is **exactly what you should work with** (strings are only good to display dates, but working on a string representation of a date is nothing you want to do).

If you need a certain string representation, create it based on the data stored in the `Date` object - or even better, get some library that adds a proper `strftime`-like method to its prototype.

The best choice for such a library is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which allows you to do this to get the string format you want:

```
moment('2013-08-19T07:54:33.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
// output (in my case on a system using UTC+2 as its local timezone):
// "2013-08-19 09:54:33"
```

However, when sending it through a socket (which requires a string representation) it's a good idea to use the default one since you can pass it to the `new Date(..)` constructor on the client side and get a proper `Date` object again.

Comment: thiefMaster , It really coming too weird to me. I 've checked on MySQL several times , but there is nothing wrong in Database, also adding message function in Node, there is no problem .

Comment: It's NOT a MySQL issue. You DO get the correct date. But you get it as a `Date` and not as a string because a date is a date and not a string after all.

Comment: SO it means, i need to re-format strtotime after fetching date rows with Node.js ?

Comment: @InnaKamoze: Absolutely, You need to format it after fetching. The best choice for such a library is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Wouldn't it be the most simplest to format the time when retrieving the column from mysql? Something like:  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,"%Y-%m-%d %T") as time FROM yourtable;`   Or am I missing something?

Comment: That would be a good option, too, if the OP really just wants to send it away as a string and not perform any date-specific operations on it in his server-side JS code.

Comment: I solved that issue with using sub string and string replacement function in iOS part . I just pushed data from Node with full date format and i handled in mobile section . :)

Comment: I'm sure the iOS APIs have a way to parse date strings. This would most likely be the better solution!

Comment: ThiefMaster , Yes ios have NSTimeFormatter class. You can parse any string in time format with that class. Also it can set Timezone ( UTC-GMT) automatically by taking your local device time-zone settings..